# NSData size and NSUserDefaults

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

Is there any reason why storing a NSData object of say ~50MB into NSUserDefaults might be a bad idea?

There's nothing about it in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but whenever I see NSUserDefaults being used, it's usually for fairly small amounts of data. I figure storing in NSUserDefaults is simpler than storing in a file though, so I would like to use it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As NSUserDefaults stores objects as property lists, so there's the possibility that it will use a text (XML)-format plist and not a binary one. In this case, NSData will send ints description into the file, which is 2 times bigger than its real size, as it, in fact, is the hexadecimal representation of the data (plus space padding, etc...)
2. It's conceptually misused/abused then. User defaults are, well, the user's defaults. That is, they should be used to store preferences/settings, not whole files. That is the task of file handling APIs (C stdio functions, NSFileHandle, etc...)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because converting 50 MB of binary data to/from a property list is incredibly inefficient. In such cases direct file IO is the only sane choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your app's `NSUserDefaults` domain is written to disk as an XML property list. When an XML plist contains an NSData, the data is represented in text in hexadecimal (plus some whitespace for readability) -- each byte in your data becomes two characters of text, so your 50 MB data becomes 100 MB.

What's more, property lists aren't random access files: if you (or in this case, Apple's implementation of `NSUserDefaults`) want to read a value in a property list on disk, the entire file is read and parsed to create an `NSDictionary`. If you make a change and want it persisted to disk, the entire dictionary is serialized and written out to a file. Thus, Reading and parsing or serializing and writing takes a lot longer for a 100 MB file than a 1 kB file. This will happen any time you (or some code in Apple's frameworks, since they use `NSUserDefaults` internally on occasion) call `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`, which may happen many times over the lifecycle of your app.

If you already have an NSData, it's not hard to put it in a file yourself -- that's what `-[NSData initWithContentsOfFile:]` and `-[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` are for. (And it's only a line or two more to get a path for reading/writing in the app's docs directory; see the Xcode project templates for several examples.)

Answer (score 0):

And any other application that accesses the user's defaults will have to spend the time to read and parse your 100 MBytes.